# Bitcoin to ether lost on transaction via Bity.com

Tags: lost-bitcoins

Today I (tried to) use bity.com to change BTC to ETH from an Electrum to a MyEtherWallet account I was. I sent the funds using the bity.com provided specific address, but the transfer from Electrum was not complete before the transaction at bity.com was registered. bity.com cancelled the transaction, however Electrum completed it! Transaction: 9fb533c74e634e1b1756663cb0e0d5e6865268f4d7ed7250b7694b230dd927b9 and now I have transferred the funds, but not received the ETH. I have written bity.com, but no response yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: ethereum.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

we've double checked. you have received the corresponding ETH here: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7828e72fb692f51a42a626b08b99b0719ad25deaa0fdedd7c1f26d183e482ca8